Issues in drawing a networkx graph in Python 3.11.8, networkx 2.6.3 and matplotlib 3.8.1
I recently upgraded to Python 3.11.8 from Python 3.11.6, and I started encountering an error "TypeError: '_AxesStack' object is not callable" when using nx.draw() to draw a network. This goes away if I provide axes manually to this function, or if I use nx.draw_networkx() instead. However, the drawing is not as expected, the nodes are either clumped together in a corner or the edges are misplaced when I set axis limits to address the clumping.
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    K33 = nx.complete_bipartite_graph(3, 3)
    print(nx.spring_layout(K33))
    nx.draw_networkx(K33, pos = nx.spring_layout(K33))

Using the code above, I get the following figure:
(https://i.sstatic.net/TEaVX.png)
    K33 = nx.complete_bipartite_graph(3, 3)
    print(nx.spring_layout(K33))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_xlim([-2.5, 5])
    ax.set_ylim([-2.5, 5])

    nx.draw_networkx(K33, pos = nx.spring_layout(K33), ax = ax)

When I add axis limits manually, as in the code above, this is the output:
(https://i.sstatic.net/dWLQm.png)
The behavior is the same when I draw nodes and edges separately (using nx.draw_networkx_nodes() and nx.draw_networkx_edges()) or when I use a different layout.
Any advice is appreciated.

Do the issues persist with the latest version of Networkx? The first issue was a bug that was fixed August last year, i.e. in Networkx version 2.8.6.

It does not in networkx 3.3. But I have another dependency (karateclub) that requires networkx <2.7 so I have to use 2.6.3. I was using this version earlier with no issues, the problem began when I upgraded Python.
